# Detect duplicated row in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am going to check the `email` not being exists in database, and then store the row with other attributes.

Here is my code do detect duplicate `email` value:

```
public boolean exists(String value) {
    customerDao.openSessionWithTransaction();
    Query query = customerDao.openSession().createQuery("from Customers where email=? ");
    query.setString(0, value);
    if (query.getFirstResult() != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But `getFirstResult()` always returns `null`, even when i check with a duplicate `email` value.

I had declared `uniuness` annotation to `pojo` class.

Here is my table:

[image]

When i check with a duplicate email value, just an `ConstraintViolationException` happens.

Comment: When you say *check with a duplicate email value*, you mean attempt to add a new row with the same email address?

Comment: @christopher I need to return `true` when email exists in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need this:

```
public boolean exists(String value) {
    customerDao.openSessionWithTransaction();
    Query query = customerDao.openSession().createQuery("from Customers where email=? ");
    query.setString(0, value);
    if (query.uniqueResult()!= null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your query to:

```
select count(*) from Customers where email=?
```

then instead of checking getFirstResult(), just use:

```
return (((Number)query.uniqueResult()).intValue() > 0);
```

Then it will return true if there is 1 (or more, but your table  doesn't allow that) or false if there are 0  rows with that email address.